# Lost citations on Scholar

Tags: citations, google-scholar

Checked my citation score and it turns out three citations (from 3 different articles) disappeared over the weekend. How can this be explained? I just hope it's some weird bug in the crawler. Anything i could do about it?

Comment: stay zen and patient ;-) There is also a google alert mail system which informs you when someone is citing your work, so you don't have to check every week...

Comment: yeah but why did these disappear even when the publication is alive and well?

Comment: It is probably impossible to tell for sure, but it could be that there where duplicate citations (from different versions of the same paper). It would make sense that when the papers are identified as versions of the same (e.g. merged by the author on its Scholar account), the n citations become only 1.

Comment: error in "matrix" ;-) There are also other search engines (paywalled) like web of science (ISI)

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner: not in this case, no. There are no duplicate papers.

Comment: Are they *good* citations? Sometimes webpages that google search for references are have wrong metadata and references can be duplicated. I have 2 citations in my most cited paper that are the same. Sometimes google fixes stuff. They also never read the emails about this, or at least they never respond.

Comment: @AnderBiguri OK thanks, so there's no way I can manually 'add' the citation?

Comment: @Alex nope, Google works in mysterious ways.

Comment: @Alex You cannot add citations manually to Google Scholar.

Comment: The reason given by @BenoîtKloeckner is the most common.  You may just be “in between” versions, i.e.the paper goes from arXiv to journal and there is a shot lull in the data.  Note this is a time of year when this happens a lot as papers distributed in 2018 are published in 2019 with ensuing readjustment of the counting algorithm, subtracting citations from 2018 and adding them to 2019.

Comment: The simplest thing to do is stop worrying about your citations. It is sort of like worrying about the number of 'friends' on Facebook. Worry about doing good research and writing good papers - those are things you control or influence. Whether people cite you or not is just something to accept.

Comment: @JonCuster the OP's question was about Scholar's algorithm seeping citations, not about why people were not citing them.

Answer (score 7):

> How can this be explained?

Since the Google algorithm is closed source, only Google can tell.

> Anything i could do about it?

No. You could try to write Google but I don't know any case where this turned out to be succesful.

Comment: thanks: this is so weird, I just found the article that cited me, it's alive and well. Why did the citation disappear?

Comment: @Alex I'm sorry, but since the Google algorithm is closed source, only Google can tell.